# Values not updating in while loop

Tags: c#, while-loop

I'm created a wpf application in Visual Studios 2017. I'm currently trying to find the nearest datetime in an ordered list of datetimes. It appears that my "nearest" value isn't getting updated within the loop, but everything looks correct to me.

Here's my code

```
while (r < dataTable.Rows.Count)    //get nearest value to the current target
{
    long nearest = long.MaxValue;
    long dtDiff = 0;
    while(nearest > dtDiff)
    {
      DateTime dtCurr = Convert.ToDateTime(dataTable.Rows[r][dtCol].ToString());
      dtDiff = Math.Abs(dtTarget.Ticks - dtCurr.Ticks);
      if(dtDiff < nearest)
      {
          Debug.WriteLine("Smaller value found r:" + r);
          Debug.WriteLine("diff:" + dtDiff.ToString() + " nearest:" + nearest);
          nearest = dtDiff;
          r++;
       }
       else
       {
          Debug.WriteLine("nearest value found " + r);
          long v = long.Parse(dataTable.Rows[r][dtCol + 1].ToString());
          values.Add(new NormValue { datetime = dt, value = v});
          dtTarget.AddSeconds(inc);
          break;
        }
    }
}
```

In the *if(dtDiff < nearest)* statement, the *nearest* variable should be updated but according to my debug print statements, it never changes. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

edit:
This is an example of what the datatable would look like:

01-May-16 00:00:10

01-May-16 00:00:40

01-May-16 00:01:10

01-May-16 00:01:40

01-May-16 00:02:10

01-May-16 00:02:40

01-May-16 00:03:10

my target datetime values goes up in increments so it would be like

01-May-16 00:00:10

01-May-16 00:00:20

01-May-16 00:00:30

01-May-16 00:00:40

So it is possible to use the same values or skip values completely

Comment: Seems complicated! Is the code inside `if(dtDiff < nearest)` being executed, i.e. the debug statements? You say you have a list, but you actually have a datatable - this might be simpler (to read, if nothing else) if you had a list of datetimes instead of a datatable requiring retrieval and casting.

Comment: Yes the debug statements are being executed which is how I found out that _nearest_ never gets updated. It never goes into the else statement. Yeah, this is a datatable but I'm more or less treating it like a list. I may change it to an actual list later like you suggested

Comment: @Jummi, Well it'll never goes into else because your difference will always be less than long.MaxValue so after reading first date it'll always go inside if condition

Comment: @Bijan I added an edit in my post to show you what my data looks like. So the nearest value isn't necessary the next value in my case.

Comment: does target always increase with a fixed value?

Comment: @Bijan Yes. Once the nearest value is found, the target will increase with a fixed value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second loop (`while(nearest > dtDiff)`) needs that nearest is bigger than dtDiff, but, in the if statement (`if(dtDiff < nearest)`), program set nearest with the dtDiff value. Set `while(nearest > dtDiff)` as `while(nearest >= dtDiff)` to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes... That is what I'm trying to do. The only thing is that _nearest_ is still the same value despite reassigning it to the value of _dtDiff_

Comment: Are you sure programs enter in the if statement?
And another question.
When you say "my debug print statements" what you mean this `Debug.WriteLine("diff:" + dtDiff.ToString() + " nearest:" + nearest);`?

Comment: Yes, I ment the Debug.WriteLine statements

Comment: It always prints the long.MaxValue for nearest. In the first "while(nearest > dtDiff)" iteration first prints the value and then set the value, so the printed value is long.MaxValue. A second iteration nevers happends because now nearest equal to dtDiff, as says my response.

Answer (score 3):

"nearest" has the same value because of the outer loop. Every time the program goes to the outer loop, "nearest" gets the new value. Try declaring "nearest" outside the loop.

```
long nearest = long.MaxValue;
while (r < dataTable.Rows.Count)
{
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: I think he actually wants to reset nearest value when code goes out of inner while loop

Comment: If program only goes once in the inner loop or does not go to the inner loop in the last iteration of the outer loop then he will get "long.MaxValue" in the "nearest" variable. . . May be that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need for a second loop. You can try this code instead:

```
DateTime dtCurr = Convert.ToDateTime(dataTable.Rows[r][dtCol].ToString());
long nearest = dtCurr.Ticks - (dtCurr.Ticks % (System.TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond * inc));
//nearest += (System.TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond * inc);
```

It calculates the nearest number smaller than `dtCurr.Ticks` with step size equal to `inc` seconds. Uncommenting the last line gives the next number.

Comment: Oh okay I will give this a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of looping a fixed range of indexes is to use a for-loop. The value `nearest` must be initialized **before** the loop, otherwise it will always be reset.

I don't understand the purpose of the inner while-loop. One loop alone should do the job. Also, I don't understand why `dtTarget` is incremented during this process.

Another problem is that your `Debug.WriteLine` comes before assigning the `nearest` value, therefore you always see the previous one.

```
long nearest = long.MaxValue;
for (int r = 0; r < dataTable.Rows.Count; r++) {
    DateTime dtCurr = Convert.ToDateTime(dataTable.Rows[r][dtCol].ToString());
    long dtDiff = Math.Abs(dtTarget.Ticks - dtCurr.Ticks);
    if (dtDiff < nearest) {
        nearest = dtDiff;
        Debug.WriteLine($"Smaller value found at: {r}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"diff:{dtDiff} nearest:{nearest}");
    }
}
```